# How to sum two different array if their name match

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my two object from two different URL.I want to sum or add item distribution array if name match

```
0:
cancelTenders: 1
closeTenders: 7
itemDistribution: Array(4)
0: {name: "Mobile", quantity: 18472.8}
1: {name: "Laptop", quantity: 20117.535000000003}
2: {name: "Tablet", quantity: 2609.75}
3: {name: "Watch", quantity:6205}


1:
cancelTenders: 0
closeTenders: 0
itemDistribution: Array(3)
0: {name: "Mobile", quantity: 26290.65}
1: {name: "Laptop", quantity: 11844.774}
2: {name: "Tablet", quantity: 416.8}
```

I want to add two different array if their name match result like this

```
0: {name: "Mobile", quantity: 44,763.45}
1: {name: "Laptop", quantity: 31,962.309}
2: {name: "Tablet", quantity: 3,026.55}
3: {name: "Watch", quantity: 6205}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first merge both arrays, 
Then use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to make an object for each `key` and finally use `Object.values` to achieve the output you want.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {name: "Mobile", quantity: 18472.8},
  {name: "Laptop", quantity: 20117.535000000003},
  {name: "Tablet", quantity: 2609.75},
  {name: "Watch", quantity:6205}
]

const arr2 = [
  {name: "Mobile", quantity: 26290.65},
  {name: "Laptop", quantity: 11844.774},
  {name: "Tablet", quantity: 416.8}
]

const res = Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, curr) => {
   if(!acc[curr.name]) {
     acc[curr.name] = curr;
   } else {
     acc[curr.name].quantity += curr.quantity;
   }
    
   return acc;
   
}, {}));

console.log(res)
```

references:

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) 
[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) 
[merge arrays with spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#A_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays)